# Causing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closed')

Tags: javascript

In our website, when I click Submit button, it shows that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closed')`. May I know why `closed` is null and not working and How can I fix it? Error is causing at `if(!(window.opener.closed))` line.

```
<a href="javascript:done1(1);" onMouseOver="submiti.src='/web/graphics/icons/submito.gif'" onMouseOut="submiti.src='/web/graphics/icons/submitu.gif'"><IMG name="submiti" border="0" src="/web/graphics/icons/submitu.gif" width="60" height="22"></a>

<script language="javascript">

function done1(v_hwde)
{
    if(!(window.opener.closed))
    {
        var data=document.tinform1.tirtby.value;
        if(v_hwde == '1'){
            var data1=document.tinform1.hwlocde.value;
            window.opener.document.tinform.hwlocde.value=data1;
        }
        window.opener.document.tinform.tirtby.value=data;
        window.opener.document.tinform.submit();
    }
    window.close()
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message doesn't say `closed` is `null`.

It says you are trying to read `something_that_is_null.closed` and since `null` can't have properties (named `closed` or otherwise), that is an error condition.

`window.opener` is null. The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) lists several reasons why that might be the case:

> In the following cases, the browser does not populate window.opener,
> but leaves it null:
>
> - The opener can be omitted by specifying rel=noopener on a link, or passing noopener in the windowFeatures parameter.
> - Windows opened because of links with a target of _blank don't get an opener, unless explicitly requested with rel=opener.
> - Having a Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header with a value of same-origin prevents setting opener. Since the new window is loaded in
>   a different browsing context, it won't have a reference to the opening
>   window.

Comment: So, How can I fix it in my code?

Comment: @JaoTa — You've provided no information about the page that triggered the opening of the window you are running this code on, so I've no idea beyond "Figure out which of the conditions I quoted from MDN apply and change it".